# Parse a string into an object in JS

Tags: javascript, parsing

Given a string of two values delimeted by `/`
Where the first value in `resourceType` and the seccond is `uuid`
So, here `resourseType` is `Patient` and `uuid` is `a444-b333-c222-d111`

```js
const testString = 'Patient/a444-b333-c222-d111'
```

I need to parse `testString` to get an Object or something where I can have access to `resourseType` and `uuid`

Comment: You can simple use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` on the string to create an array of values and then create an object using the values therein.

```js
const testString = 'Patient/a444-b333-c222-d111';
const testArray = testString.split("/");
const testObject = {
  resourceType: testArray[0],
  uid: testArray[1]
};
console.log(testObject.resourceType);
console.log(testObject.uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to split the data inside the string.

```
const testString = 'Patient/a444-b333-c222-d111'

const ParseText = () => {
const Object = testString.split('/') 
console.log(Object);
}

 ParseText();   //Calling the function to check the console.log()
```

Take a look to the code above: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-grothendieck-0csu2?file=/src/index.js:301-455